# Disable dates in pickadate (JavaScript) after enabling some specific dates

Tags: javascript, calendar, pickadate

I am using the pickadate library so the user can select dates. All dates should be disabled by default. This works by adding `disabled: [true]`.

```
var myPicker=$("#inputDatetime").pickadate(
    {
        format:"dd. mmmm yyyy",
        formatSubmit:"yyyy-mm-dd",
        min:dt,
        selectYears:2,
        close:"Schliessen",
        today:"Heute",
        selectMonths:!0,
        disable: [true]
    }
), picker = myPicker.pickadate("picker");
```

After this I am enabling some [dates](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#disable-dates-all):

```
picker.set('disable', activeDays);
```

Now I want to be able to have blacklisted weekdays. For example all mondays and all wednesdays should always be blocked. I have this data in another variable:

```
var disabledDates = [1, 3];
```

How do I make sure the weekdays are disabled after that I enabled some specific dates?

Comment: Look if it is this, what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/2j4f9dh8/2/

Comment: Yes, that looks pretty good. Please put it into an answer.

Comment: I've added an answer for it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below:

```
var $input = $("#datepicker").pickadate({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    formatSubmit: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    editable: false,
    min: new Date(),
    firstDay: 0
});

var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
picker.set("disable", [
    1,
    [2016, 5, 29],
    [2016, 6, 9],
    [2016, 8, 8]
]);

picker.set("enable", [
    [2016, 5, 19],
    [2016, 5, 26]
]);
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2j4f9dh8/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get`](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-get-disable) method to get already listed enabled and disabled dates and just push weekdays indexes you want to disable:

```
picker.set('disable', activeDays);
var disabledDates = picker.get('disable').push([1, 3]);
picker.set('enable', true); // Enable all days to be sure we will not flip  disabled/enabled states
picker.set('disable', disabledDates);
```

Don't forget to enable dates before disabling them. In this case they will not flip to opposite values.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns `TypeError: datesToDisable.map is not a function. (In 'datesToDisable.map', 'datesToDisable.map' is undefined)`

Comment: @doonot do you have your page live example somewhere?